# C# WPF DataGrid Binding MVVM - Binding master ViewModel (container of child ViewModels) to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have two C# (VS 2019 - .Net Framework 4.8) ViewModels, **AllAirportsVM** and **AirportVM**.

An instance of **AllAirportsVM** maintains a **List**<**AirportVM**> and has a bindable member **CurrentAirport** of type **AirportVM**.

I have a DataGrid in an **AllAirportsView** and I would like to set its ItemSource to the **List**<**AirportVM**> of my instance of **AllAirportsVM**, where I understand the DataGrid's DataContext, for purposes of defining the contents of its columns, should be the class **AirportVM**.

But if the DataGrid's DataContext is set to a class of ViewModel (**AirportVM**), how then do I bind my instance of **AllAirportsVM** to the DataGrid, such that when the user selects a row in the DataGrid, the **CurrentAirport** property of my instance of **AllAirportsVM** gets set/updated?

I have limited experience working with DataTemplates and RelativeSources so wondered if the solution to my problem involved them somehow and I just wasn't aware.

Thanks in advance for any advice or links to other articles or discussions that might help me.

Comment: If you bind the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` to a `List<AirportVm>`, you are *not* setting the `DataContext` of the entire DataGrid.  You are not changing that at all.  Instead you merely setting the `DataContext` for each ***item in the DataGrid***.  So that the ColumnBindings will bind each row to a separate instance of an `AirportVm`

Comment: You say: 'But if the DataGrid's DataContext is set to a class of ViewModel (AirportVM)'..


If you have something like this `DataContext="{Binding AirportVM}"` then you can not bind neither the `ItemsSource` nor `SelectedItem` to properties that are not exist in AirportVM class..

but if you have your `DataContext` of type `AllAirportsVM`, then you have access to the property of type `List<AirportVm>` and the property `CurrentAirport`.. 

Please submit some code snippets to clarify the question more

Comment: Why don't you share code ?

Answer (score 0):

the datagrid should look something like

```
<!--Datacontext here is AllAirportsVM-->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AllAirportsVM}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentAirport}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- columns bind to Properties of a AirportVM-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` (or rather its parent window or `UserControl`) should be an instance of the `AllAirportsVM` view model class.

You would then bind the `ItemsSource` property directly to the `List<AirportVM>` property of the view model:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Airports}" />
```

By default, the `DataGrid` will then generate a column per each public property of the `AirportVM`.

So, in other words, if you bind the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<T>` property, you will get a column for each public property of the type `T` (where `T` is `AirportVM` in your case).